# Necesito omitir un número en una lista con Python

Tags: python

Tengo que imprimir una lista desde el 1 hasta el 30 sin el número 25 con el ciclo for in en visual studio python

Comment: Preguntas de este tipo no son para nada bien recibidas, por favor lee [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/modificaci%c3%b3n-de-la-p%c3%a1gina-c%c3%b3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta/4433#4433) y date cuenta de que estoy hablando. Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es asignar el bucle `for i in range` dentro de una lista con los  números a imprimir removiendo solo el número 25, es decir de esta manera:

```
list = [i for i in range(31)]
list.remove(25)
print(list)
```

Comment: Bro, tienes buena intención y se valora mucho :D Hay algo a consdierar: como dice el buen @gbianchi: "Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida". Si seguimos respondiendo preguntas así, seguirán apareciendo... Al menos espera a que el OP edite la pregunta con lo que ha intentado. Gracias por tu colaboración con el sitio. Saludos :D

Comment: Si la verdad se me paso por alto , por la facilidad del ejercicio, de hecho lo estaba editando ahora mismo para explicar  paso a  paso el ejercicio para la  persona que preguntó, pero si no es considerable puedo eliminarlo y que los  moderadores lo valoren. gracias

Comment: Considera que el OP tampoco ha pasado por el recorrido (sin medalla de "informado"). En todo caso, ten la respuesta lista en un block de notas y la editas cuando el OP agregue más detalles, ¿te parece?

Comment: Muchas gracias Guillermo, era muy simple ahora que veo, aunque yo lo tenía diferente asi
print("Imprimir del 1 hasta 30 sin el 25")
a = 1
for a in range(1, 31, 1):
    print(a)
    a = a + 1
print("Fin")

Comment: Y no sabía como omitir el 25 y lo estaba porbando con if y elif